# How to convert .while loop to .repeat .untilcxz loop?

Tags: assembly, masm

I have the following code in Intel assembly language and I want to write the loop in terms of .repeat .until and .repeat .untilcxz directives. However, I hope the one on the RHS implements the first directives and I ask how to load ecx with the right number of iterations to implement the second directives on LHS?

*Note: The code I am asking about implements the division operation in terms of iterative subtraction.*

```
mov eax,x                         mov eax,x
mov edx,eax                       mov edx,eax
mov ebx,y                         mov ebx,y
mov eax,0                         mov eax,0
mov ecx,??                        .repeat
.repeat                           sub edx,ebx
sub edx,ebx                       inc eax
 inc eax                          .until edx < ebx
.untilcxz
```

The while loop code equivalent is written as,

```
mov edx,eax
mov eax,0
.while  edx >= 
sub edx,ebx
inc eax
.endw
```

Answer (score 1):

The trip-count for a repeated-subtraction loop is the result you're trying to calculate in EAX.  Computing an iteration count ahead of time would defeat the entire purpose and make it redundant to actually loop.

Of course, `div` is more efficient than repeated-subtraction unless the quotient is very small, like under 10 or so, so you should use `div` anyway instead of looping at all.

---

BTW, using those silly MASM directives is less efficient in this case than using the FLAGS results of `sub` yourself.  I assume `.until edx < ebx` will assemble to a cmp / jl (or `jb`?  IDK if it assumes signed or unsigned).  But `cmp` is redundant if you put the `sub` last; it already sets FLAGS.

What does `.untilcxz` do exactly?  Does it assemble to a `loop` instruction that decrements ECX?  Or does it only test the current value?  Or use `jecxz` over a `jmp`?

You could maybe abuse `.untilczx` by modifying ECX inside the loop.  Like `setl cl` or `setb cl` after the subtraction to set the low byte of ECX to 0 or 1 depending on whether the `sub` crossed zero (signed or unsigned).  Of course `xor ecx,ecx` before the loop so CL = ECX.

This seems silly and totally pointless, but if you just want to play with those directives you could consider it I guess.

Comment: Actually, this is an exercise in the book, "Guide to assembly language, a concise introduction" by James T. Streib that I am following to learn some generalities regarding the title, It asks the same question I posted here. So it's my point to know how to use .repeat .untilcxz directives for unassigned number of iterations.

Comment: My guess to the solution is,

mov ecx,edx
.repeat
.if ecx > ebx
sub edx,ebx
inc eax
mov ecx,edx
.endif
.untilcxz